# ClickOnce installing dialog icon

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, icons, clickonce

For some reason the icon displayed in the ClickOnce installing dialog doesn't look right:

[image: SourceLog ClickOnce installing dialog icon issue]

It's supposed to look something like this:

[image: SourceLog icon 32x32]

I have the icon in my Visual Studio solution with various "Image Types", but I'm not sure which one I need for the ClickOnce install dialog..

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this same problem with a similarly themed icon consisting of a small symbol on a solid background. The solution is to select an unused color and use it for the lower left corner of the image, which the ClickOnce installer will use for transparency. In this case, and the case of my image, the color it was picking was the majority of the image, hence the result shown above.

[image: transparent]
I found that I needed to modify the color of the lower-left pixel in our icon to be a different color than the rest of the background, in order for the ClickOnce install dialog to properly display the image.
[image: modified icon]
 The result is what we see below, it is treating that black pixel as the color to use for transparency. 
[image: corrected]

Comment: Awesome, would have searched ages to get this straight ;)